# How to make useEffect rerun only on change of a single dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a custom input component that has an attached 'edit/submit' button, like so:

[image]........................... 
[image]

I want the onChange handler passed to it to fire only when user hits the submit button i.e. (✓) and not on every keypress. So, in useEffect I did:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!editMode) { // only on submit
        onChange(value) // "value" is a state of my component
      }
    }, [editMode])

    return (
     <div className='my-input'>
      <input value={value} onChange={({target}) => setValue(target.value)}/>
      <Icon 
        name={editMode ? 'tick' : 'pencil'}
        onClick={() => setEditMode(editMode => !editMode)}
      />
     </div>
    )
```

But the linter starts to bang:

> useEffect has missing dependencies: 'onChange' and 'value'...

How to fix this issue or am I using an incorrect hook here?

Answer (score 3):

The warning you're seeing is because your `useEffect` function *doesn't* depend on a key press, it depends on the value of `onChange` and `value`. A better way to accomplish this might be to send the event inside of the `onChange` handler itself:

```
const onClick = React.useCallback(() => {
  const nextEditMode = !editMode
  setEditMode(nextEditMode)
  // If we're flipping editMode on, fire the event.
  if (nextEditMode) {
    onChange(value)
  }
}, [value, onChange])
```

`useEffect` should be used when you can only represent the thing you want as a side-effect, but there's no need to do that in this case; this can handled in event handler, and it is easier to read when you do so.

Comment: I want the `props.onChange` to be fired only on submit icon click but this will start to fire `props.onChange` on every keypress or wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I wrote this answer before you amended your question.

Comment: The updated answer should serve your needs. It will only fire `onChange` on an icon click if `editMode` is going from `false` to `true`. This will prevent the parent component "knowing" about changes to the input value until the icon is clicked :).